# Getting \n returned in jquery and not sure why

Tags: jquery, html, location, ip

I created a site a month ago at work and there is a section where I get the user's IP address and current location and display it. It was working fine up until I went on the website today and the location part is no longer working.

The IP returns the proper IP but for the location returns: \n

This is what i see:

Detected IP Address: the correct IP

Location: \n, \n  (instead of city, state)

I asked the few people at work who have access to the code and they all told me they never touched anything.

Anyone know what happened, that can just cause code to seemingly just stop working overnight?

HTML

```
       <div class="warning-info">
            Detected IP address: <span class="yellow" id="ip"></span><br>
            Location: <span class="yellow" id="address"></span><br><br>             
        </div>
```

Jquery code

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html(response.ip);
    $("#address").html(response.city + ", " + response.region);
}, "jsonp");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the site page, they recommend to use `$getJSON`, you can try the following:

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io', function(data){
      $("#ip").html(data.ip);
      $("#address").html(data.city + ", " + data.region);
    });
});
```

This piece of code is working on my local environment`(Apache+PHP)`

Comment: Your code displays the same problem BUT i realized it may be an internal issue here at the office. When i tried the site on my phone and turned wifi off it works! lol

Comment: Maybe there is some network related issue: like I said before, I create a php file, put your html, include jquery on the `head` and my code at the end of the `body` tag and it all works as expected